# Каскад keepalived не пропускает трафик по порту.

Tags: web-apps

Ситуация:
клиент ==80==> keepalived1 ==80==> keepalived2 ==80==> nginx

С keepalived2 до nginx телнет ходит.
С keepalived1 уже нет.
С клиента, разумеется, тоже нет.

Помогите, плз, разобраться, в чем может быть затык.

конфиг keepalived1:

```
virtual_server 1.1.1.1 80 {
    delay_loop 2
    lb_algo lc
    lb_kind NAT
    persistence_timeout 50
    protocol TCP
    real_server 192.168.3.11 80 {
        weight 1
        TCP_CHECK {
            connect_port 80
            connect_timeout 3
            nb_get_retry 3
            delay_before_retry 2
        }
    }
}
```

конфиг keepalived2:

```
virtual_server 192.168.3.11 80 {
    delay_loop 2
    lb_algo lc
    lb_kind NAT
    persistence_timeout 50
    protocol TCP
    real_server 2.2.2.2 80 {
        weight 1
        TCP_CHECK {
            connect_port 80
            connect_timeout 3
            nb_get_retry 3
            delay_before_retry 2
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, куда копать, что смотреть? Извелся уже весь. ipv4 routing включен, если что.
Если ситуация непонятна, могу скинуть дополнительную инфу.